# Organize my routines, diets and tasks

Tags: windows, android, calendar

The specs I need are at least this:

- Easy programmable alarm for routines (things I'm going to do every day/week)
- The capacity to add notes or descriptions to those routines (like what I need to eat or what exercises I have to do)
- Work on Android or Windows 10; the data does not have to be synced between these two.

I prefer something with Google Calendar integration, but I'm OK without it. I don't mind paying for the software if it's good enough.

Comment: Questions like these have been asked before, I was unable to find a specific duplicate. Search the site questions with [is:q reminder](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+reminder)

Comment: No, I didn't care about sync data. I just say I have both OS and I am OK about using one or another.
And yes, I know there are similar questions, but maybe there are one software who are oriented to what I am searching.